# Http request Kotlin Android

Tags: android, kotlin

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, не получаться отправить http запрос на сервер. Вылетает ошибка "No Network Security Config specified, using platform default". В манифесте добавил android:usesCleartextTraffic="true", но не помогло. Для отправки использую библиотеку Khttp. Возможно кто-то сталкивался с подобной проблемой.

```
override fun getToken(email: String, password: String) {

    val client = OkHttpClient()

    val formBody = FormBody.Builder()
        .add("email", "artur.yashchenko@nure.ua")
        .add("password", "123123")
        .build()
    val request = Request.Builder()
        .url("http://192.168.0.101:8080/login")
        .post(formBody)
        .build()

    try {
        val response = client.newCall(request).execute()
        print(response.body)
        // Do something with the response.
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }

}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".activities.ProfileActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".activities.CreateOrderActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".activities.InnerOrderActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".activities.MyOrdersActivity">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".activities.SignUpActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".activities.MenuActivity">

    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".activities.MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: ua.nure.gms, PID: 5377
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1565)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:389)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:230)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:212)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:436)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:621)
    at okhttp3.internal.platform.AndroidPlatform.connectSocket(AndroidPlatform.kt:58)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.kt:268)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.kt:176)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:236)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findHealthyConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.find(ExchangeFinder.kt:77)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.Transmitter.newExchange$okhttp(Transmitter.kt:162)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.kt:35)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:112)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:87)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.kt:82)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:112)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:87)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.kt:84)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:112)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:71)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:112)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:87)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.kt:184)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.kt:66)
    at ua.nure.gms.repositories.impl.AuthenticationRepositoryImpl.getToken(AuthenticationRepositoryImpl.kt:30)
    at ua.nure.gms.activities.MainActivity$onCreate$1.onClick(MainActivity.kt:19)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102)
    at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Comment: Код нужно выкладывать текстом. Исправьте, пж-та вопрос.

Comment: А `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` должно работать. Возможно у вас некорректно обновление кода произошло. Попробуйте удалить приложение и заново установить из студии.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запрос отправляется в основном потоке, нужно вынести из UI потока в другой.

Можно было и загуглить ошибку...