# Отправка Http запросов с клиента на Kotlin(android)

Tags: kotlin, http, httpclient

Цель - при клике на Button отправить http запрос с методом GET на локальный сервер. После двух вечеров с бубнами вышло что то вроде этого:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


        val reqButton: Button = findViewById(R.id.reqbutton)
        reqButton.setOnClickListener {
            lifecycleScope.launch {
                val result = makeRequest()
                println(result)
            }
        }

    }

    private suspend fun makeRequest(): HttpStatusCode {
        val client = HttpClient(CIO)
        val response: HttpResponse = client.get("http://localhost:8080")
        println(response.status)
        return response.status
    }
}
```

Для создания http клиента воспользовался библиотекой io.ktor.
Ну и собственно после клика по кнопке программа завершается с ошибкой: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused ...

И если не трудно, в дополнение посоветуйте, что лучше использовать для работы с http. А также хорошие практики по построению архитектуры Http клиента

Comment: "Connection refused"  означает только одно - сервер не хочет с вами общаться. Почему? Я предположу, что вы банально не туда стучитесь. `localhost` на Андроиде -- это он сам (Андроид), а не какой-то ваш локальный сервер.

Ответ на второй вопрос очень зависит от того, что вы собираетесь делать. Для простых сценариев может быть достаточно встроенного OkHttp клиента: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1056107/http-request-kotlin-android

Comment: Вопрос комментатору выше. С каких пор OkHttp стал встроенным клиентом?)

Comment: с локалхостом разобрался, заменил хост на свой ipv4. Можете еще подсказать по поводу того, какую конструкцию для запроса нужно использовать в рамках setOnClickListener(в своем примере я использовал lifecycleScope.launch). Ответ на вопрос, что я собираюсь делать - регистрация(своя), аутентификация своя и через гугл(возможно позже добавятся другие подобные сервисы), во всем остальном по больше части CRUD(будут сложные выборки, но на стороне сервера, на клиентской части думаю ничего сверхестественного)

Comment: @Circassian, насчет встроенного погорячился. Привык что он всегда под рукой.